# Can you open a LibreOffice Draw file in MS Publsiher?

Tags: lubuntu, libreoffice

I've been searching for quite a while, and all I've found is where LibreOffice added support to be able to open MS Publisher files in Draw.  But I will soon be putting lubuntu on my parents computer, and my mom uses Publisher a lot for work (teacher), and she does some stuff at home.  If she opens a publisher file, edits it, then tries to open it at work, will she be able to?  If not, is there another program that this will work with?  If not, it looks like my only option will be to put VB or VM Ware on an eight year old computer and install XP in there and hope it doesn't die...

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two other answers are invalid; they talk about opening MS Publisher files in Libre Office, not the other way round. But the answer is no, MS Office doesn't support any Libre Office file; they are already a bit in danger of the **free** alternative solution becoming more popular. They will **surely** not support anytime soon... Yet as an alternative, you can export it as a PDF, as shown below:

[image: Screenshot of exporting as PDF]

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. I emailed my mom a file saves as flat XML hoping she would be able to open it (I knew .odf and .odg (I think?) were out of the question), but she hasn't had a chance to look at it yet. Does this apply to Scribus too?

Comment: @HollisScriber I've never used or heard of Scribus before, but why use it when you have LibreOffice which is more stable, known and cross-compatibility compliant

Comment: Because I'd like to avoid trying to run VB inside lubuntu on an eight year old computer with 2GB of RAM at all costs. If Scribus files can be opened in Publisher, then I'll use that.  If not, VB it is...

Comment: @HollisScriber I don't get it... How does using Scribus make you avoid running Virtual Box, while LibreOffice gives the same functionality (as far as I know)

Comment: MS Publisher will not allow you to open a PDF, yet edit it.

Comment: Because my mom needs to open files she does at home (in lubuntu) at work (in Windows, on Publisher). She's not going to abandon Publisher at work where she has it, but is going to have to at home, because their XP system is virus ridden and dying quickly.

Comment: @HollisScriber I'm on Ubuntu, so if you could give us a list of file formates supported by MS Publisher, we would be able to further help you

Answer (score 0):

probaby your mom can open the file check this out

http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/14/can-i-use-microsoft-publisher-files-with-libreoffice/

Comment: Yeah, I found that, but it's talking about opening Publisher files in Draw, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Libreoffice should, but if you don't like the results, try Scribus.

> Scribus is a desktop publishing (DTP) application. Scribus is designed
>   for flexible layout and typesetting, and the ability to prepare files
>   for professional quality image setting equipment. It can also create
>   animated and interactive PDF presentations and
>   forms.<sup>[Scribus](http://www.scribus.net/canvas/Scribus)</sup>

To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:scribus/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install scribus-trunk
```

For more info see their [website](http://www.scribus.net/canvas/Scribus)

[image]

Comment: Glad to hear LO should do the trick. I've seen some stuff about Scribus, but I was just afraid it may be too steep a learning curve for my mom, she's kind of set in her ways of the MS Office suite, and Draw looked more similar.  I'll definitely keep it in mind though if Draw doesn't work.  Thanks!